# Haskell return type polymorphism with class restriction

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, return-type

Is there a way to achieve something like this without wrapping types in some kind of helper container?

```
class TestClass a where
    returnInt :: a -> Int

data TestData0 = TestData0
data TestData1 = TestData1

instance TestClass TestData0 where
    returnInt _ = 0

instance TestClass TestData1 where
    returnInt _ = 1

testisFunction :: (TestClass a) => Int -> a
testisFunction 0 = TestData0
testisFunction 1 = TestData1
```

Comment: Just to make sure the problem is clear: `TestClass a => Int -> a` means the caller -- as opposed to you, the implementer -- gets to choose what `a` should be.

Comment: No, the caller should only get "something" that implements `TestClass` he should have no way of knowing if he got `TestData0` or `TestData1`.

Comment: See [existential types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type), but I suppose that counts as a helper container. In which case the answer is no.

Comment: That's what you want to do; my point is that the signature `TestClass a => Int -> a` doesn't express it. As luqui mentions, an existential wrapper addresses that by hiding the information from the caller.

Comment: I believe we see this universal/existential confusion with typeclasses roughly once a month or two. Probably this confusion is due to OOP subtyping, which programmers are trying to emulate. Perhaps we need a reference question/answer, so that these sort of questions can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been answered in other questions before, you can use an existential wrapper:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialTypes #-}

data SomeTest = forall a. TestClass a => SomeTest a

instance TestClass SomeTest where
  returnInt (SomeTest t) = returnInt t

testFunction :: Int -> SomeTest
testFunction 0 = SomeTest TestData0
testFunction 1 = SomeTest TestData1
```

Then the usage is:

```
returnInt (testFunction 0) == 0
```

However, in answer to your specific question, it *is* possible to avoid this wrapper by turning your code “inside out” with *continuation-passing style*, converting the (rank-1) existential type into a (rank-2) universal type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

testFunction :: Int -> (forall a. TestClass a => a -> r) -> r
testFunction 0 k = k TestData0
testFunction 1 k = k TestData1
```

Then instead of consuming the result of `testFunction`, we pass a function that will accept its result. Crucially, this function must work `forall a. TestClass a`, so it doesn’t know anything about the type `a` other than that it’s an instance of `TestClass`. The usage changes to:

```
testFunction 0 returnInt == 0
```

Remember, top-level `forall` is implicit in type signatures, so this says that the caller of `testFunction` decides what `a` is:

```
testFunction ::           TestClass a => Int -> a
testFunction :: forall a. TestClass a => Int -> a
```

And that type is equivalent to this:

```
testFunction ::           Int -> (forall a. TestClass a => a)
```

Moving the `forall` one level inward, so it applies to the continuation `k`, means that `testFunction`, the caller of `k`, now decides what `a` is. The caller of `testFunction` now decides what `r` (the result type) is by passing in a particular `k`.

```
testFunction :: forall r. Int -> (forall a. TestClass a => a -> r) -> r
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a wrapper of some kind.